# Google play services invitation process for cards based game

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am considering google play services for my cards game which requires 4 players to start. The only problem is that I am not sure how I can get a people started on one game. According to Docs, you can have a user host a game that will invite random players. The problem is that invites will be sent to people but many people wont be close to their phone. If 3 invites were sent to random players and only one joined, then the game can not start. How can I design multiplier given this limitation?

The problem that the concept of listing rooms does not exist therefore people can not join the game that the person hosted as I cant query the list

Any idea? Or  am I miss understanding the concept

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the Quick game option to auto-match randomly selected opponents you won't have this problem. Because it doesn't invite 4 random players of all users that have google play game services installed. It just connects 4 players that are currently starting a quick game.
You only have a problem if there are not enough users that start a quick game at the same time.

If you are using the "Auto-pick player" option from the Player Invitation Dialog, it's the same. If you choose a friend in the list and then the auto-pick player, the two remaining players will be filled with random players that are awaiting a quick game.

Comment: Is there a way I can have the person play with his FB freinds?